# Why does removing a cookie work in localhost and not our https sites?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, https

My team is in the process of converting PHP code into React and we have the two "different" sites stitched together currently. The login process hits the PHP, sets a cookie with the JWT, then redirects to one of the React pages. When logging out via a React page, we are able to remove the cookie when in localhost, but the same code does not work when deployed live on any of our https sites. These are the different variations I've attempted:

```
document.cookie = cname + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
document.cookie = "[COOKIE NAME]= ;domain=[DOMAIN]; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
document.cookie = "[COOKIE NAME]= ;domain=[DOMAIN];path=[PATH]; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
document.cookie = "[COOKIE NAME]= ;expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";
document.cookie = "[COOKIE NAME]= ;maxAge=-99999999;";
document.cookie = document.cookie.split(';').filter(c => !/^\s?[COOKIE NAME]=/.test(c)).join(';');
```

These are the various solutions I've found throughout my search. I even looked into the code of react-cookie and they are using the `expires` trick.

**Dictionary:**

- COOKIE NAME = name of cookie (obv)
- DOMAIN = value listed in the domain column when viewing cookies in the Application tab
- PATH = value listed in the path column when viewing cookies in the Application tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after weeks of looking into this issue I finally found a solution.
The PHP was creating the cookies with a domain of the pattern `dev.mysite.com`. I noticed that I could alter cookies in the console if, and only if, the cookies had a domain with a leading period (.). I switched the PHP to add a leading period to the domain when the cookies are created and now the React is able to manipulate them.

Note: I'm open to people telling me this is a terrible idea, but this solution worked for us.